# Benchmark for loop and range operator

Tags: swift, loops, for-loop, benchmarking

I read that range-based loops have better performance on some programming language. Is it the case in Swift. For instance in Playgroud:

```
func timeDebug(desc: String, function: ()->() )
{
    let start : UInt64 = mach_absolute_time()
    function()
    let duration : UInt64 = mach_absolute_time() - start

    var info : mach_timebase_info = mach_timebase_info(numer: 0, denom: 0)
    mach_timebase_info(&info)

    let total = (duration * UInt64(info.numer) / UInt64(info.denom)) / 1_000
    println("\(desc): \(total) µs.")
}

func loopOne(){
    for i in 0..<4000 {
        println(i);
    }
}

func loopTwo(){
    for var i = 0; i < 4000; i++ {
        println(i);
    }
}
```

range-based loop

```
timeDebug("Loop One time"){
    loopOne(); // Loop One time: 2075159 µs.
}
```

normal for loop

```
timeDebug("Loop Two time"){
    loopTwo(); // Loop Two time: 1905956 µs.
}
```

How to properly benchmark in swift?

// Update on the device

**First run**

Loop Two time: **54 µs**.

Loop One time: **482 µs**.

**Second**

Loop Two time: **44 µs**.

Loop One time: **382 µs**.

**Third**

Loop Two time: **43 µs**.

Loop One time: **419 µs**.

**Fourth**

Loop Two time: **44 µs**.

Loop One time: **399 µs**.

// Update 2

```
    func printTimeElapsedWhenRunningCode(title:String, operation:()->()) {
        let startTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
        operation()
        let timeElapsed = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - startTime
        println("Time elapsed for \(title): \(timeElapsed) s")
    }


    printTimeElapsedWhenRunningCode("Loop Two time") {
        loopTwo(); // Time elapsed for Loop Two time: 4.10079956054688e-05 s
    }

    printTimeElapsedWhenRunningCode("Loop One time") {
        loopOne(); // Time elapsed for Loop One time: 0.000500023365020752 s.
    }
```

Comment: oh yes, but still loopOne is slower.

Comment: You have observed that the "normal" for loop is faster than a range-based for loop (which I can confirm). But what is your question?

Comment: In the Playground range-based for loop is slower, but on the device is faster. Check update

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. All your numbers show that "loop one" (which is the range-based loop) is slower. In any case: what is your question? Are you asking *why* one is faster or slower? Or are you assuming that your benchmarking method is wrong?

Comment: Yes I thing the benchmarking method is wrong because the original code divide by 1_000_000, but that returns 0 for the both loops.

Comment: Integer division *truncates* the result to an integer, so if the time is less than one millisecond (= 1,000,000 nanoseconds) then division by 1_000_000 will give zero. Change your code to `let totalMilliSeconds = (Double(duration) * Double(info.numer) / Double(info.denom)) / 1_000_000` to avoid that problem.

Comment: Using your code returns Loop Two time: 0.0589583333333333 µs.
Loop One time: 0.354875 µs. but using different benchmark method the result is different

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn’t really benchmark in playgrounds since they’re unoptimized.  Unless you’re interested in how long things will take when you’re debugging, you should only ever benchmark optimized builds (`swiftc -O`).

To understand why a range-based loop can be faster, you can look at the assembly generated for the two options:

**Range-based**

```
% echo "for i in 0..<4_000 { println(i) }" | swiftc -O -emit-assembly -
; snip opening boiler plate...
LBB0_1:
    movq    %rbx, -32(%rbp)
; increment i
    incq    %rbx
    movq    %r14, %rdi
    movq    %r15, %rsi
; print (pre-incremented) i
    callq   __TFSs7printlnU__FQ_T_
; compare i to 4_000
    cmpq    $4000, %rbx
; loop if not equal
    jne LBB0_1
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    addq    $8, %rsp
    popq    %rbx
    popq    %r14
    popq    %r15
    popq    %rbp
    retq
    .cfi_endproc
```

**C-style `for` loop**

```
% echo "for var i = 0;i < 4_000;++i { println(i) }" | swiftc -O -emit-assembly -
; snip opening boiler plate...
LBB0_1:
    movq    %rbx, -32(%rbp)
    movq    %r14, %rdi
    movq    %r15, %rsi
; print i
    callq   __TFSs7printlnU__FQ_T_
; increment i
    incq    %rbx
; jump if overflow
    jo  LBB0_4
; compare i to 4_000
    cmpq    $4000, %rbx
; loop if less than
    jl  LBB0_1
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    addq    $8, %rsp
    popq    %rbx
    popq    %r14
    popq    %r15
    popq    %rbp
    retq
LBB0_4:
; raise illegal instruction due to overflow
    ud2
    .cfi_endproc
```

So the reason the C-style loop is slower is because it’s performing an extra operation – checking for overflow.  Either `Range` was written to avoid the overflow check (or do it up front), or the optimizer was more able to eliminate it with the `Range` version.

If you switch to using the check-free addition operator, you can eliminate this check.  This produces near-identical code to the range-based version (the only difference being some immaterial ordering of the code):

```
% echo "for var i = 0;i < 4_000;i = i &+ 1 { println(i) }" | swiftc -O -emit-assembly -
; snip
LBB0_1:
    movq    %rbx, -32(%rbp)
    movq    %r14, %rdi
    movq    %r15, %rsi
    callq   __TFSs7printlnU__FQ_T_
    incq    %rbx
    cmpq    $4000, %rbx
    jne LBB0_1
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    addq    $8, %rsp
    popq    %rbx
    popq    %r14
    popq    %r15
    popq    %rbp
    retq
    .cfi_endproc
```

#### Never Benchmark Unoptimized Builds

If you want to understand why, try looking at the output for the `Range`-based version of the above, but with no optimization: `echo "for var i = 0;i < 4_000;++i { println(i) }" | swiftc -Onone -emit-assembly -`.  You will see it output a *lot* more code.  That’s because `Range` used via `for…in` is an abstraction, a struct used with custom operators and functions returning generators, and does a lot of safety checks and other helpful things.  This makes it a *lot* easier to write/read code.  But when you turn on the optimizer, all this disappears and you’re left with very efficient code.

#### Benchmarking

As to ways to benchmark, this is the code I tend to use, just replacing the array:

```
import CoreFoundation.CFDate

func timeRun<T>(name: String, f: ()->T) -> String {
    let start = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
    let result = f()
    let end = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
    let timeStr = toString(Int((end - start) * 1_000_000))
    return "\(name)\t\(timeStr)µs, produced \(result)"
}

let n = 4_000

let runs: [(String,()->Void)] = [
    ("for in range", {
        for i in 0..<n { println(i) }    
    }),
    ("plain ol for", {
        for var i = 0;i < n;++i { println(i) }    
    }),
    ("w/o overflow", {
        for var i = 0;i < n;i = i &+ 1 { println(i) }    
    }),
]

println("\n".join(map(runs, timeRun)))
```

But the results will probably be meaningless, since jitter during `println` will likely obscure actual measurement.  To really benchmark (assuming you don’t just trust the assembly analysis :) you’d need to replace it with something very lightweight.

Comment: That's interesting. In your tests, a range-based loop is faster, while OP claims that a C-style loop is faster. I actually get very different results, depending on the number of iterations, and also depending on which one (loopOne or loopTwo) is measured first.

Comment: For small `n`, LLVM will unroll some loops as well.  I deleted the benchmark since multiple tests showed it was very variable – mainly because the `println` dwarfs the the time of the loop itself. A true benchmark would need to do something more lightweight inside the loop (but enough to dissuade the optimizer from just deleting it!).  I suspect the OP was testing in a playground, which is essentially meaningless, what you’re benchmarking is really the playground magic.

Comment: Also, in unoptimized builds, the `Range` object will really exist.  In optimized builds, structs often disappear and are replaced by registers. Just reinforces the point, it really doesn’t make sense to benchmark `-Onone`

Comment: Sure. I replaced `println()` by a call to a global function `foo(i)` which modifies a global variable, and tested it in a compiled project with optimization (standard "Release" configuration). I had cases where the C-style loop was faster, but I cannot reproduce it anymore :) – The overflow checking is definitely a good point!